# Cant figure out this SQL Trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

so I'm suppose to be making a trigger for my database that will limit how many classes a faculty member can be assigned. If QUALIFIED = 'Y', then they can teach up to three classes. the trouble i'm running into is that I dont know what is wrong with my SQL statement that wont let it be run.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE trigger "ASSIGN_T1"
BEFORE
INSERT ON "ASSIGN"
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    DECLARE
         A_COUNT NUMBER;
         A_QUALIFY CHAR(2);
    
    SET(SELECT QUALIFY FROM QUALIFY WHERE (FID = :NEW.FID)) AS A_QUALIFY
    SET(SELECT COUNT(FID) FROM QUALIFY WHERE (FID = :NEW.FID)) AS A_COUNT

    IF (A_QUALIFY = 'Y' AND A_COUNT < 3) THEN
           INSERT INTO ASSIGN (FID, CID) VALUES (:NEW.FID, :NEW.CID);
    END IF;
END;
```

The two errors i'm getting are

> line 8, position 8 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following: constant exception  table long double ref char time timestamp

> line 8, position 61 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "AS" when expecting one of the following:  set

Comment: Thank you all for the help, I finally got it to work. I've taken on C++ and Python and even Assembly with not a lot of problems, but for some reason SQL is proving difficult for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1st problem here is that the BEGIN needs to move down below the DECLARE and the variable declarations.

The 2nd problem is the way you're attempting to set those variables. Get rid of those SETs and AS's.  In PL/SQL, one valid way to set a variable with the result of a SQL statement is with a SELECT INTO. Like so....

```
  SELECT QUALIFY
  INTO A_QUALIFY
  FROM QUALIFY
  WHERE FID = :NEW.FID;
```

...and you can do the same for A_COUNT

I won't guarantee everything will work right after you do that, but that's the bare minimum to fix here.

Also, even if doing the above works, watch out for SELECT INTO because you'll get a "no data found" error if there's *ever* a scenario where you don't already have a FID = :NEW.FID being passed in OR an "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows" error if you have more than 1 existing record with that FID in your table.  You then either have to handle those exceptions, or use a different method of assigning values to your variable (such as declaring the SQL in a cursor and then OPEN cursor, FETCH cursor INTO variable, CLOSE cursor.)

Lastly, I think there may be a problem in your logic. You're asking for the value in QUALIFY for a FID, but then you're asking for the number of records that have that FID.  That implies that the FID isn't the primary key on your table, which means there could be different records with the same FID but different values in the QUALIFY field. So if you're going to be using that variable in your logic later on, then that may be a problem, since the same FID can have one record with QUALIFY = 'Y', and another record with QUALIFY = 'N'

Comment: You most certainly CAN have a `DECLARE` as part of the PL/SQL block which forms the body of a trigger. [See this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8384077a483ab317905ff4f76ef0d0d7).

Comment: You're completely right, I mistakenly lumped triggers with procedure and function creation where DECLARE isn't used, and the problem here was that the BEGIN was in the wrong spot. Thanks for catching. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have used the BEGIN after DECLARE part. And am not sure why you are using SET .. AS. We can combine both selects into one and use it in IF condition.

I don't think you can trigger on the same table and do insert at the same time. You will end up with ORA-04088 error.

Instead, you can restrict the insertion by throwing an error.
(my option would be a Foreign Key Constraint over the ASSIGN table)

```
--Creating Tables
   create table ASSIGN  (FID number,      CID number);
   create table QUALIFY (FID number,    QUALIFY char);
    
-- Loading sample data
insert into QUALIFY values (1, 'Y');
insert into QUALIFY values (1, 'Y');
insert into QUALIFY values (1, 'Y');
insert into QUALIFY values (2, 'Y');
insert into QUALIFY values (2, 'Y');
insert into QUALIFY values (3, 'N');
insert into QUALIFY values (4, 'Y');

CREATE OR REPLACE trigger "ASSIGN_T1"
BEFORE
INSERT ON "ASSIGNEE" --< change table name to yours
FOR EACH ROW
 DECLARE
     A_COUNT NUMBER;
 BEGIN    
  SELECT COUNT(QUALIFY) into A_COUNT FROM QUALIFY WHERE QUALIFY='Y' AND FID = :NEW.FID;
    
  -- If they are qualified and already has 3 classes. They are not allowed/record is not inserted.
  IF  A_COUNT = 3 THEN
  Raise_Application_Error (-20343, 'FID is not Qualified or already has 3 Classes.');
  END IF;
 END;
/
```

Test by inserting data into the ASSIGNEE table

```
-- FID 1 already assigned to 3 classes, should not be allowed any more.
insert into ASSIGNEE values (1,3);
-- See error below
Error report -
ORA-20343: FID is not Qualified or already has 3 Classes.

-- FID 2 has only 2 classes, so allowed to insert.
insert into ASSIGNEE values (2,3);
1 row inserted.
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish your goal is to do something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ASSIGN_T1
  BEFORE INSERT ON ASSIGN
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  FOR aRow IN (SELECT q.QUALIFY,
                      COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY q.FID) AS FID_COUNT
                 FROM QUALIFY q
                 WHERE q.FID = :NEW.FID)
  LOOP
    IF aRow.QUALIFY = 'Y' AND aRow.FID_COUNT < 3 THEN
      INSERT INTO ASSIGN (FID, CID) VALUES (:NEW.FID, :NEW.CID);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END ASSIGN_T1;
```